# Laravel Eloquent Inner Join Query with dynamic Multiple conditions in Where Clause

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.4

In the following Eloquent Query Example, as we can see, I am trying to add condition in where clause only if its value is received in $request data.
I am getting error for writing if in between of the Eloquent query for checking isset. Is there a way to add conditions dynamically only if it is set?

```
 SampleMaster::from('sample_master as sm')          
        ->join('example_master as em', 'sm.e_id', '=', 'em.id')
        ->select(['sm.col1','sm.col2','em.col3'])     
        if(isset($request->sample_id))
        {
           ->where('sm.sample_id',$request->sample_id) 
        }
        if(isset($request->example_id))
        {
            ->where('sm.example_id',$request->example_id) 
        }
        if(isset($request->f_id))
        {
            ->where('sm.f_id',$request->f_id) 
        }
        if(isset($request->g_id))
        {
            ->where('sm.g_id',$request->g_id) 
        }            
        ->groupby(['sm.col1','sm.col2','em.col3'])
        ->get()->all();
```

Also I want to generalize the Eloquent Query such that if none of the parameter is passed then there should some default like 1 as we get to see in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `sample_master` WHERE 1
```

so that I can directly go on appending key=>values in $where_array if present, in case when I am not using joins.